# gnuplot grid remove grid from axes lines

Tags: gnuplot

`gnuplot` adds grid lines even on axes, it can cause unpleasant effects:

```
set logscale x
set xrange [0.01:100]
set xtics font ",12"
set x2tics font ",12"
set mxtics 10
set ytics font ",12"
set y2tics font ",12"
set grid xtics mxtics ytics lt 0 lw 3, lt 0 lw 0.5 behind
set grid
plot sin(x)
```

Especially if one then plots the above to `eps`, it looks like there are both logarithmically spaced and linearly spaced tics on the x-axis. Is there any nice way to get rid of the grid lines at axes? A workaround would be to make the axes thicker, but that is not the way I want. I really want to delete those grid lines.

To explain what I mean
[image]

The linearly spaced tics that are seen in the picture are actually the dotted grid, so it has nothing to do with tics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown, there *are* both log and linear tics along x. That is because both the x axis and the x2 axis are contributing tics to both the top and bottom borders.  You can turn that off with

```
set tics nomirror
```

Are you asking how to make the range of the tics smaller than the range of the axes?  In the plot you show, that would be

```
set yrange [-1:1]
set ytics -0.8, 0.2, 0.8
set ytics add (-1 2, 1, 2)
```

The last command adds back explicit tics at y=-1 and y=1 without generating a corresponding grid line. See documentation for `set xtics list`

Comment: If you look at the image I posted, these are tics on x axis. Take a look at the tic above 10. To the right of that tic (and to the left as well), there are very short vertical lines that are linearly separated and span the whole x axis. They are not tics (they are shorter than `mxtics`), they are part of the grid line that coincides with x axis (`set grid`). In this particular case the line type of the grid and the line with are such that the line is visible even though it is in the background (behind x axis as set by `set grid xtics mxtics ytics lt 0 lw 3, lt 0 lw 0.5 behind`).

Comment: The issue is how to get rid of grid line that coincides with the `x1,x2,y1,y2` axes lines. Changing the line style with which the axes are plotted is bad solution. Better solution is disabling gridlines and adding horizontal lines manually as plots `y=...` and vertical lines as `set arrow` which is incredible amount of work in some cases.

Comment: Did you try the commands I suggested?  Grid lines are drawn only at the position of an axis tic.  By removing the final axis tic from the plot it also removes that grid line.

Comment: I did, but those have the unpleasant effect on missing the y tics at the bottom and at the top which makes the plot look bad, the 1 and -1 should be plotted on y axis...

Comment: So OK, add them back at a tic level that doesn't trigger a grid line. Level 0 generates major tics and major tic grid lines, level 1 generates minor tics and minor tic grid lines, levels 2 and above generate no grid lines.   (Added to answer)

Comment: yes, or I can just generate arrows instead of grid lines, it really probably depends on particularities of the plot which workaround is better.